# Best way to enable/disable elements in the form based on selected value in drop down menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have form with access level fields. Based on selected value more fields will be enabled on the form. Here is example of my form:

```js
$('#frm_accesslevel').on('change',accessLevel);
function accessLevel() {
    var fldVal = $(this).val();

    switch(fldVal){
        case '1':
            break;
        case '2':
            break;
        case '3':
            break;
        case '4':
            break;
        default:
            
    }
}
```

```html
<!---*** Start: JQuery 3.3.1 version and chosen files. ***--->
<script language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="Chosen/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Chosen/chosen.min.css">
<!---*** End: JQuery 3.3.1 version and chosen files. ***--->
<!---*** Start: Bootstrap 3.3.7 version files. ***--->
<script language="javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="Bootstrap_Confirmation/bootstrap-confirmation.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!---*** End: Bootstrap 3.3.7 version files. ***--->

<form name="frmSave" id="frmSave>
  <div class=" form-group ">
    <label class="control-label " for="accessl "><span class="label label-primary ">Access Level:</span></label>
    <select class="form-control " name="frm_accesslevel " id="frm_accesslevel " required>
      <option value=" ">--Choose Level--</option>
      <option value="1 ">Level 1</option>S
      <option value="2 ">Level 2</option>
      <option value="3 ">Level 3</option>
      <option value="4 ">Level 4</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group required ">
    <label class="control-label " for="region "><span class="label label-primary ">Region</span></label>
    <select class="form-control " name="frm_region " id="frm_region " required disabled></select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group ">
    <label class="control-label " for="state "><span class="label label-primary ">State:</span></label>
    <select class="form-control " name="frm_state " id="frm_state " required disabled></select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group ">
    <label class="control-label " for="city "><span class="label label-primary ">City:</span></label>
    <select class="form-control " name="frm_city " id="frm_city " required disabled></select>
  </div>
  <div class="row ">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-1 col-lg-1 ">
      <button type="submit " class="btn btn-primary ">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

I'm wondering how to achieve next, if user selects `Level 1` then none of disabled field should change the status. If `Level 2` selected then only Region drop down should be enabled, and if `Level 3` selected then Region and State should be enabled. Very last is `Level 4` then Region, State and City should be enabled. Going back and forth between the levels I would like to enable/disable Region/State/City input fields. What would be the most efficient solution?

Answer (score 1):

How about this?
If there's more than 3 selects, then you can iterate through an array with selects names to avoid duplicate the .hasClass part.

```js
$("#frm_accesslevel").change(function() {
    var selected = $("#frm_accesslevel option:selected");
    
    $('.enabler').each(function(){
      $(this).prop("disabled", true);
    });
    
    if(selected.hasClass('region')){
      $('#frm_region').prop("disabled", false);
    }
    if(selected.hasClass('state')){
      $('#frm_state').prop("disabled", false);
    }
    if(selected.hasClass('city')){
      $('#frm_city').prop("disabled", false);
    }
});
```

```html
<!---*** Start: JQuery 3.3.1 version and chosen files. ***--->
<script language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="Chosen/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Chosen/chosen.min.css">
<!---*** End: JQuery 3.3.1 version and chosen files. ***--->
<!---*** Start: Bootstrap 3.3.7 version files. ***--->
<script language="javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="Bootstrap_Confirmation/bootstrap-confirmation.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!---*** End: Bootstrap 3.3.7 version files. ***--->

<form name="frmSave" id="frmSave">
  <div class=" form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="accessl"><span class="label label-primary">Access Level:</span></label>
    <select class="form-control" name="frm_accesslevel" id="frm_accesslevel" required>
      <option value="">--Choose Level--</option>
      <option value="1">Level 1</option>S
      <option value="2" class="region">Level 2</option>
      <option value="3" class="region state">Level 3</option>
      <option value="4" class="region state city">Level 4</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group required">
    <label class="control-label" for="region"><span class="label label-primary">Region</span></label>
    <select class="form-control enabler" name="frm_region" id="frm_region" required disabled></select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group ">
    <label class="control-label" for="state"><span class="label label-primary ">State:</span></label>
    <select class="form-control enabler" name="frm_state" id="frm_state" required disabled></select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="city "><span class="label label-primary ">City:</span></label>
    <select class="form-control enabler" name="frm_city" id="frm_city" required disabled></select>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this:

```
$('#frm_accesslevel').on('change', function(){

var fldVal = $(this).val(); // you have access to this here, not outside

 switch(+fldVal) {//cast as number with +
    case 1:
        alert("nothing happen");
        break;
    case 2:
        $(".form-control").hide();//hide all
        $("#frm_region").show();
        $("#frm_accesslevel").show();
        break;
    case 3:
        alert("behavior");
        $(".form-control").show();//show all
        break;
    case 4:
        alert("other behavior");
        $(".form-control").show();//show all
        break;
    default:
        alert("somethig wrong");
} 

});
```

Keep in mind you have errors in html , some " are missing and you have spaces in id's properties.

this is a simple and functional example https://jsfiddle.net/k2nuq3h3/5/

Comment: Even if this works, I think he's looking for the best way to do it. Like the title says. How about mine?

Comment: @NiMusco I think OP approach is not bad. Your approach is more scalable of course. Otherwise if we have hundreds of selects we'd need another approach too.